# On Informix, how do I programmatically drop a unique constraint whose name is unknown?

Tags: sql, informix

I have a table with a column that has had a unique constraint placed on it.

Now we find that we need to eliminate this incorrect constraint.

The constraint was not explicitly named.

I can get the name of the constraint in question with this query:

```
SELECT
s.constrname
  FROM informix.sysconstraints s
 INNER JOIN informix.systables t ON t.tabid = s.tabid
 INNER JOIN informix.syscolumns c ON c.tabid = t.tabid
 WHERE t.tabname = 'the_table'
   AND c.colname = 'the_column'
   AND s.constrtype = 'U'
```

Now I need to dynamically provide this constraint name to the `DROP CONSTRAINT` statement.

I suppose I could create a stored procedure that does this with variables and the concatenation operator, then run it, then kill it.  Surely there's a faster, cheaper, single-shot way to do this?  `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` or something like it—though I confess from reading its documentation that I don't see how that statement in particular can help me here.

This must run on Informix 11.5 and higher.  Thanks for any help here.

Comment: I would do it as a shell script. It would be very easy to code.

Comment: Thank you.  I should have mentioned this has to be done in either SQL or Informix-flavored SPL.

Comment: Has to? If the rules are stupid, change the rules.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work I think:

```
echo 'unload to t.sql delimiter " " select "alter", "table", t.tabname, "drop", \
"constraint", s.constrname from informix.sysconstraints s inner join <...etc>' \
dbaccess yourdatabasename; cat t.sql | dbaccess yourdatabasename
```

Put the rest of your query instead of `<...etc>`, obviously. This whole thing should be on one line -- I put backslashes where I split it for easier reading.

The first command generates the `ALTER TABLE` statement and saves it in a file; the second executes the generated file.

Comment: Thank you; I should have mentioned this has to be done in either SQL or Informix-flavored SPL.  That is, I do not have shell scripting as an option.

Answer (score 0):

Knowing you, you probably have Java... why can't you use it? You'd need to provide the table_name and column_name dynamically I suppose? Or would this always be for the same table/column?
If these change, you already have some dynamic data... so why not construct the statement in any language and then execute it?
But yes, the "language" could be SPL... IDS 11.50 supports the EXECUTE IMMEDIATE in SPL.
I may be missing something, but usually SQL doesn't allow getting part of the statement dynamically by "embedding" a query. Do you know any DB that does that?
Regards.

Comment: Hi; I'm using [Liquibase](http://liquibase.org).  Specifically, I'm using the `<sql>` tag, and the SQL that I run has to be Informix-specific, since Informix does not support the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` schema.  Does that help?  Regarding the dynamic nature: In SQL Server I am sure that I could do something with the `sp_execsql` stored procedure, an anonymous SPL-like code block, and the concatenation operator without the need to create a stored procedure, execute it, and drop it.

Answer (score 0):

The constraint name you find with your query probably begins with a blank (space).  To be able to drop the constraint by name, you need to generate an SQL statement containing the name inside double quotes, and you need to run the SQL statement with the DELIMIDENT environment set (its value actually doesn't matter, but choose 1 for simplicity).

Does 11.50 include dynamic SQL in SPL? I think that was an 11.70 feature.  If it is available, then obviously that's what you'll use. If not, you'll have to create the SQL and run it via DB-Access or equivalent.